# HttpWebRequest, c# and Https

Tags: c#, ssl, https, httpwebrequest

I have tried many ways to login to an https website programmatically, but I am having issues.  Every time I get an error stating that my login and password are incorrect.  I am sure they are correct because I can login to the site via the browser using the same credentials.

## Failing Code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.majesticseo.com/account/login?EmailAddress=myemail&Password=mypass&RememberMe=1");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,**;q=0.8";
request.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.CookieContainer = container;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

//String tmp;
foreach(Cookie cookie1 in response.Cookies)
{
    container.Add(cookie1);
}

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

string html = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine("" + html);
```

Comment: Where in your code are you setting the credentials? What is the purpose of all the commented out code? Is it relevant to the question? If not, delete it.

Comment: Well obviously you're not doing BASIC auth, so I can't really advise you what fields need to be set since I have no idea what this website is. Also please format and clean up this code, it's remarkably confusing in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

That site uses HTTP POST for login, and does not send the username and password in the URL.

The correct login URL is `https://www.majesticseo.com/account/login`

You need to create a string of data to post, convert it to a byte array, set the content length and then do your request.  It is very important that the content-length is sent.  Without it the post will not work.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.majesticseo.com/account/login?EmailAddress=myemail&Password=mypass&RememberMe=1");

        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0";
        request.Referer = "https://www.majesticseo.com/account/login";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,**;q=0.8";
        request.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

        // the post string for login form
        string postData = "redirect=&EmailAddress=EMAIL&Password=PASS";
        byte[] postBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

        System.IO.Stream str = request.GetRequestStream();

        str.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

        str.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();


        string html = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("" + html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to post something (I don't see, what, from your code) but not credentials. I guess that your web page shows you a web form where you enter username (email address?) and password. Then the browsers *posts this form*. Consequently you need to replicate browser behavior - encode form contents and send them in your post request. Use some webmaster developer tools for popular browsers to see what exactly the client browser sends to the server and how it encodes form data. Next, it's very likely that your request requires special cookies which you can collect by visiting another page (eg. login page). Sending preset cookies (like you do in commented code) won't work for most sites.

In other words, proper mechanism is:

1. GET the login web page
2. collect cookies
3. POST form data and pass collected cookies in the request.
4. collect other cookies, which could have been sent after login.

Comment: I was trying in this way but this was'nt working. First solution is working (sending login data as a bytes array).   Thank you.

Comment: @jars well, I don't think anybody will be able to help you here without debugging your code and checking your particular site. So you're out of luck here.